# kernel-adaptation-pc : error building this package

Tags: tizen

I have an error building a particular package kernel-adaptation-pc of TIZEN .

please help me out.

Arch =  i586

The logs are attached below:

$:~/tizbuild/kernel/kernel-adaptation-pc$ gbs build -A i586 --include-all

info: generate repositories ...

info: build conf has been downloaded at:
      /var/tmp/vivek-gbs/tizen2.0.conf

info: start building packages from: /home/vivek/tizbuild/kernel/kernel-adaptation-pc (git)

info: prepare sources...

info: start export source from: /home/vivek/tizbuild/kernel/kernel-adaptation-pc ...

info: the following untracked files would be included:
   .gitattributes

fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref

fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref

error: Patch0 found multiple times, aborting as gbp spec/patch autoupdate likely fails

error: RPM error while parsing spec, duplicate patches found

error: Failed to export packaging files from git tree

error: no spec files to build.

error: rpmbuild fails

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the dependency urls in the gbs configure file properly.
Please share the ~/.gbsconf file.by default gbs takes this file as configuration.

Answer (score 0):

i586 has some issues finding some dependencies, try with i686 architecture.

```
$:~/tizbuild/kernel/kernel-adaptation-pc$ gbs build -A i686 --include-all
```